# Running JavaScript inside a Handlebars Template

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I want to execute a bit of Javascript code inside my handlebars template. Typically in the application I do this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var @Model.JavascriptVariableName;
    $(function () {
        @Model.JavascriptVariableName = new TagInput()
            .withAvailableTags(@Html.Raw(Model.AvailableTagsJson))
            .withAppliedTags(@Html.Raw(Model.AppliedTagsJson))
            .withMinCharsAutocomplete(@Model.MinCharsAutocomplete)
            .allowBackspaceDelete(@Model.DeleteWithBackspace.ToString().ToLowerInvariant())
            .allowNewTags(@Model.AllowNewTags.ToString().ToLowerInvariant())
            .initialize($('#@Model.ElementId'), $('#@(Model.ElementId)_hidden'));
        @if(Model.OnChangeJavascript.IsNotNullOrEmpty()) {
            @:@(Model.JavascriptVariableName).onChange = function () { @Html.Raw(Model.OnChangeJavascript) }
        }
    });
</script>
```

But since I am already inside of a handlebars template with  I tried to just insert the `$(function(){})` that just gets spit out as text which makes sense. So how then can I create a bit of dynamic Javascript inside of handlebars???

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="tagsTemplate">
<div>Tags</div>
var @Model.JavascriptVariableName;
                        $(function () {
                        @Model.JavascriptVariableName = new TagInput()
                        .withAvailableTags(@Html.Raw(Model.AvailableTagsJson))
                        .withAppliedTags(@Html.Raw(Model.AppliedTagsJson))
                        .withMinCharsAutocomplete(@Model.MinCharsAutocomplete)
                        .allowBackspaceDelete(@Model.DeleteWithBackspace.ToString().ToLowerInvariant())
                        .allowNewTags(@Model.AllowNewTags.ToString().ToLowerInvariant())
                        .initialize($('#@Model.ElementId'), $('#@(Model.ElementId)_hidden'));
                        @if (Model.OnChangeJavascript.IsNotNullOrEmpty())
                        {
                            @:@(Model.JavascriptVariableName).onChange = function () { @Html.Raw(Model.OnChangeJavascript) }
                            }
                        });
</script>
```

The above code wont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are using `handlebar` to compile your webpage server side I don't see why you need to wait every time for the `window Ready` event: `$(function(){})` in fact wrap a function to make it sure it will fire only when the DOM is ready (has been loaded).
You can simply skip that part in your code if you want.

I would strongly discourage to put JS code in a template: why don't you generalize that code and compile with Handlebars some DOM stuff with ids or classes that you can use in your "generic" function instead?